# How do I have multiple entries for my SQLite recipe table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

complete Android newbie here. So I was making a recipe database for my class, and I want a "Search By Ingredient" option for the app. However, when my listview pulls all the ingredients from the DB, they are not individual, but clumped together based on recipe.

Here is my code for the DB:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipe (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "Name TEXT, " +
            "Ingredients TEXT, " +
            "Recipe TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(sql);


    //This is the content for the Recipes. AKA the database
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("Name", "Baked Eggcado");
    values.put("Ingredients",
            "Avacado" +
            "Egg" +
            "Salt" +
            "Pepper");

    values.put("Recipe",
            "\n" +
            "Prep Time: 5 minutes\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Cook Time: 15 to 20 minutes\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Total Time: 25 minutes\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Servings: 1\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Ingredients:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "1 avocado\n" +
            "\n" +
            "1 egg\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Salt and pepper to taste\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Directions:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "1. Preheat oven to 425°F.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "2. Slice avocado in half.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "3. Scoop out pit to create hole for the egg.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "4. Place avocado in a small baking cup. Line with tinfoil for minimal clean­up.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "5. Crack the egg into the hole.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "6. Bake for 15 to ­20 minutes.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "7. Season with salt and pepper, or seasoning of your choice. If you have them, sprinkle \n" +
            "\n" +
            "chopped scallions on top");
    db.insert("recipe", "Name", values);
```

So my Question is, how do I get the listview to show "Avacado", "Egg", "Salt", & "Pepper" individually instead of all in one cell. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the ingredients as a single text item, so, when you are reading them from the database and putting them into a list item, there is only one item.

You will need to add some kind of a delimiter, let's say, a comma, to allow you to split the string you read back from the database into an array of strings.  That way, you can easily add it to the list as individual entries.

For example:

```
String[] ingredients = stringReadFromDatabase.split(",");
```

This will return an array of Strings, each with one item in them.  I didn't use a space as a delimiter, so you can still have ingredients like 1/2 Cup of Sugar.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are concatenating all recipes values in one string by using "+". So for Recipe key is giving value like this 
            "Prep Time: 5 minutes 
            Cook Time: 15 to 20 minutes
            Total Time: 25 minutes"
therefore...

```
key_is :"Recipe"
value_is:  "Prep Time: 5 minutes Cook Time: 15 to 20 minutes Total Time: 25 minutes"
```

For your expected result, You have to save your data in different structure. Follow general JSon structure to save your data.

```
{
       "Recipe":{
            "Prep Time": "5 minutes",
            "Cook Time": "15 to 20 minutes",
            "Total Time": "25 minutes"  
        }
}
```